# In ActiveMQ what is the network parameter on a VM transport for?

Tags: java, activemq-classic

In ActiveMQ I am using a static TCP connection to connect to another broker. In the logs I  notice that it says:

```
Establishing a network connection from vm://localhost?network=true to tcp://address:port
```

What is the `network=true` parameter used for on VM transport? I cannot find any reference on the ActiveMQ website or in the Javadoc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VM Transport `network=true` means that a network bridge to other broker VM Transports is enabled. This is commonly used when you have a network of brokers setup.